# How to attach image(s) to a new Trello card from the JS client library?

Tags: javascript, trello

While adding a new card with the trello_client.js library, I want to attach an image or more. [The documentation](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#post-1-cards) only mentions that `fileSource` is *"A file"*.

Data URI didn't work as is, and blobs are usually appended to FormData objects so I'm not sure how to approach this and didn't find working examples.

And is it even possible to attach multiple files along with the card creation, or only later, by separate `post`s [here](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#post-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-attachments)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The client.js library doesn't support attaching file attachments. You'll need to use a standard XHR and FormData object.

Here's some sample code: https://plnkr.co/edit/PjJsfMgJuJaM5A83RAiW

The relevant bits of HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="chooser"/>
<button onclick="upload();">Upload</button>
```

and the javascript:

```
// Setup
var TOKEN = "";
var KEY = "";
var CARD = "";

function upload() {
  var formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("token", TOKEN);
  formData.append("key", KEY);

  // HTML file input, chosen by user
  formData.append("file", document.getElementById('chooser').files[0]);

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/" + CARD + "/attachments");
  request.send(formData);
}
```

Comment: You're probably right, I'll try that direction. Thanks.

Comment: @PeEll This is only for one file. What would it look like for multiple files? Is there a way to send multiple files with one FormData Object?

Comment: @tecmec You have access to the form so if there are multiple files there, you will have to do an XHR POSTing each one.

Answer (score 3):

The Trello API expects either a URL to be attached, or a file encoded as `multi-part/formdata`.

I've put together a series of examples on different ways you can attach files to a card using Javascript. You can check it out here: https://glitch.com/~trello-attachments-api. To see the example project running live, click "Preview App."

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is completely broken