# add attachment to Trello card

Tags: javascript, canvas, attachment, trello

In my program I have a big canvas where I extract multiple selected regions and draw the regions to separate new small canvas.

I want to post the newly created canvas to trello as attachment using this [API](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#post-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-attachments) POST /1/cards/[card id or shortlink]/attachments.

The files are not saved in a database or in local storage.

I'm able to attach a Link to a card but the attaching a file is not clear and only documented with a curl command.

Is it possible to attach a Canvas and how using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

found a aprtial answer at this post [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35824891/how-to-attach-images-to-a-new-trello-card-from-the-js-client-library)

also found this example [trello attachment examples](https://glitch.com/%7Etrello-attachments-api) :